# Can we have a nontrivial division of a irreducible root system as $\Phi=\Phi_{[\lambda]}\cup \Phi_{[\mu]}$?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems, weyl-group

Let $(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h},\Phi)$ be a root system of a complex simple Lie algebra, where $\Phi$ is the set of all roots. For each $\alpha\in \Phi$, let $\alpha^{\vee}=2\alpha/(\alpha,\alpha)$ be the coroot. Let $\Lambda_r$ be the root lattice and $W$ be the Weyl group. Here the root system is irreducible.

Now for each $\lambda\in \mathfrak{h}^*$ we define
$$
\Phi_{[\lambda]}:=\{\alpha\in \Phi|(\alpha^{\vee},\lambda)\in \mathbb{Z}\}
$$
and
$$
W_{[\lambda]}:=\{w\in W|w\lambda-\lambda\in \Lambda_r\}.
$$
Jantzen has prove that $\Phi_{[\lambda]}$ is a root system in its $\mathbb{R}$-span and $W_{[\lambda]}$ is the Weyl group of $\Phi_{[\lambda]}$.

Now consider $\lambda$, $\mu\in \mathfrak{h}^*$. Then we get $\Phi_{[\lambda]}$, $W_{[\lambda]}$, $\Phi_{[\mu]}$, and $W_{[\mu]}$.

> > My question is: if $\Phi_{[\lambda]}\cup \Phi_{[\mu]}=\Phi$, then is it true that one of them must be the whole $\Phi$?

For example we consider the root system $B_2$. Let $\alpha$ be the short simple root so $\alpha^{\vee}=\alpha$. Consider $\lambda=\alpha/2$ and we can show that $\Phi_{[\lambda]}=\{\text{the four short roots}\}$. Hence to make sure that$\Phi_{[\lambda]}\cup \Phi_{[\mu]}=\Phi$, we must choose $\mu$ such that $\Phi_{[\mu]}$ contains the four long roots. But we can show that a $\Phi_{[\mu]}$ that contains the four long roots must also contain the four short roots.

Of course it is not true if we do not require that the root system is irreducible.

Comment: So it seems that we at least need $\mathrm{Span}_{\mathbb{R}}(\Phi_{[\lambda]}) = \mathrm{Span}_{\mathbb{R}}(\Phi_{[\mu]})=\mathrm{Span}_{\mathbb{R}}(\Phi)$, is that right?

Comment: @SamHopkins Actually one of $\text{Span}_{\mathbb{R}}(\Phi_{[\lambda]})$ and $\text{Span}_{\mathbb{R}}(\Phi_{[\mu]})$ must be the whole $\text{Span}_{\mathbb{R}}(\Phi)$.

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to think of an example of an irreducible crystallographic root system $\Phi$ and a non-trivial sub-root system $\Phi' \subseteq \Phi$ for which the set of "missing" roots $\Phi\setminus\Phi'$ does not span the whole space. But I can't think of one. Do you know of such an example?

Comment: @SamHopkins I cannot find one either. Maybe you are right, they both span the whole space.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is yes because $(\Phi_{[\lambda]})^{\vee}$ and $(\Phi_{[\mu]})^{\vee}$ are *closed* sub-root systems of the dual root system $\Phi^{\vee}$. Closed means if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots in $(\Phi_{[\lambda]})^{\vee}$ and $\alpha+\beta$ is a root in $\Phi^{\vee}$, then $\alpha+\beta$ is also a root in $(\Phi_{[\lambda]})^{\vee}$.

The corresponding answer for closed sub-root systems of a irreducible root system is answered for [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342875/can-we-have-a-nontrivial-division-of-a-irreducible-root-system-as-the-union-of-t).